# Derive attribute for specific fields only, like serde does

Tags: rust

Using `derive` syntax, can I implement traits like `Hash` or `PartialEq` using specific fields, not all of them?

It could look like:

```
#[derive(Debug, Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct MyStruct {
    id: i32,
    name: String,

    #[derive(hash_skip, eq_skip)] 
    aux_data1: f64,
    #[derive(hash_skip, eq_skip)]
    aux_data2: f64,
    #[derive(hash_skip, eq_skip)]
    aux_data3: String,
}
```

I want the `hash` method to only use `id`, and `name` and no others.

The [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) library allows something like this for serialization.

Comment: Related [How do I implement `Hash` for an enum with a special case?](/q/69186841/2189130) There is a crate called [derivative](https://crates.io/crates/derivative) that provides additional attribute-based custom implementations for standard traits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in Rust at this moment. What I would suggest is to use the implementation for tuples available for these traits, like this:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    aux_data1: f64,
    aux_data2: f64,
    aux_data3: String,
}

impl Hash for MyStruct {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) where H: Hasher {
        (&self.id, &self.name).hash(state);
    }
}

impl PartialEq for MyStruct {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        (&self.id, &self.name) == (&other.id, &other.name)
    }
}
```

Edit: or as @Shepmaster suggested in a comment below, you can create a `key` function which returns a tuple of all useful fields and use it.

```
impl MyStruct {
    fn key(&self) -> (&i32, &String) {
        (&self.id, &self.name)
    }
}

impl Hash for MyStruct {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) where H: Hasher {
        self.key().hash(state);
    }
}

impl PartialEq for MyStruct {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.key() == other.key()
    }
}
```

Comment: When doing this, I've found it useful to create a `key` method that returns the tuple which is then used to keep `hash` and `eq` (and whatever else) all synchronized in order and count.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks, that seems to be a good idea, especially when you want to include > 2 fields.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by using [derivative](https://crates.io/crates/derivative).

Example:

```
use derivative::Derivative;

#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Hash, PartialEq)]
struct Foo {
    foo: u8,
    #[derivative(Hash="ignore")]
    #[derivative(PartialEq="ignore")]
    bar: u8,
}
```